# How to add select options to the selection screen of ME55?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-selection-screens

I need to add `EBKN-SAKTO` as a select option in the selection screen of `ME55`. Need help doing this.

I tried looking for enhancement spots and screen that exists in the program (`RM06BF00`) related to the selection screen but couldn't find any.

Comment: As always, when you modify standard programs, you have all possibilities like Customer Exits, BAdI, Enhancement Framework, Modification of Standard, screen variants, etc. For changing a selection screen, usually, only Enhancement Framework and Modification of Standard can be used. Not specific to ME55. I could change easily.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.